# PHP: How to use cURL to interact back and forth with hardware device?

Tags: php, curl

I'm familiar with cURL for retrieving files, submitting POSTs, etc, but now I need a php script to "chat" with a networked hardware device. This device has a kind of Terminal Mode and is accessible through a shell with tools like netcat. I'm trying to reproduce that dialog with a php script.

So far I can open the connection and get the password request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.35:4025');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "DSC: $result \n"; 

// submit password
// read answer to see if password is approved
// submit command
// get command answer 

curl_close($ch);
```

How can I now submit the password as a single string, over that existing cURL connection, and keep my script interacting back and forth sending and receiving strings?

Is there a better tool than cURL for this?

The plan is to keep the connection alive forever, for monitoring purposes.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use socket [check this](http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/)

**Socket :** sockets are the fundamental "things" behind any kind of network communications done by your computer. For example when you type www.google.com in your web browser, it opens a socket and connects to google.com to fetch the page and show it to you. Same with any chat client like gtalk or skype. Any network communication goes through a socket.

Comment: Thanks. This seems more appropriate than cURL for my needs.